# Identify faces of irregular almost convex polyhedron from coordinates of vertices and plot the solid in 3D

Tags: matlab, plot, polygon, vertices, edges

I have the vertices of an irregular almost convex polyhedron, for example something that looks like an icosahedron:

```
xyz = [0.8198   -0.1474 -0.5534;
   0.3944   0.4688  0.7904;
   0.6851   0.6826  -0.2545;
  -0.6855   0.4451  0.5762;
   0.2117   -0.8247 -0.5245;
   0.8263   -0.3318 0.455;
  -0.8393   -0.502  -0.2086;
  -0.0868   -0.9484 0.305;
  -0.1256   0.9915  -0.0353;
  -0.304    -0.3252 0.8954;
  -0.7964   0.4053  -0.4489;
  -0.0817   0.1043  -0.9912];
```

I want to identify edges and faces of the polygon and plot the solid in 3D. This is what I have tried but, although close enough, it doesn't look right:

```
x = xyz(:, 1);
y = xyz(:, 2);
z = xyz(:, 3);
tri = delaunay(x, y, z);
tetramesh(tri, xyz)
```

**EDIT --> Following Chris Taylor's answer, I have realized I should also specify that the desired output "faces" should be a cell array where each element is a vector of k indices representing the vertices of that face; and similarly "edges" should be a matrix where each row is a vector of 2 indices representing the vertices which the edge connects**

Any idea?

P.S. I have tried to add the tags: polyhedron, solid, delaunay and tetramesh but the system didn't allow me to do it - perhaps someone with the privilege to create new tags could do it for me? Maybe removing less precise tags like "plot", "edges", "vertices", "polygons"?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
>> tri = delaunay3(x, y, z); // coordinates of *tetrahedrons* not triangles
>> tetramesh(tri, xyz);
```

[image]

Comment: It's not yet what I wanted but delauney3 seems to be working much better than delauney - of course! Thank you!

I want to find faces and edges of the polyhedron: each face can be stored in a cell with the indices of the k vertices and each edge in a matrix with the indices of the two vertices.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to get the faces and the edges. For each tetrahedron returned by `delaunay3` there will be one vertex inside the convex hull of the polyhedron and three on the convex hull. The face is determined by the three vertices on the convex hull, and each pair of vertices determines an edge (you can remove the duplicate edges easily enough).

Answer (score 0):

After Chris Taylor's comment, I have tried this:

```
x = xyz(:, 1);
y = xyz(:, 2);
z = xyz(:, 3);
dt = DelaunayTri(xyz);
[ch v] = convexHull(dt);
h_tri = trisurf(ch, dt.X(:,1), dt.X(:,2), dt.X(:,3), 'FaceColor', 'cyan');
hold on
h_plot = scatter3(x, y, z, 'filled', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r');
axis square
axis off
```

It seems much more like what I had in mind, and variable "ch" stores the vertices of each triangular face which is pretty much what I wanted.

The only thing that I find disappointing - but this will probably require much more analysis on my side - is that I know that this polyhedron should *look like* an irregular icosahedron (possibly not convex, but "almost" convex) while the code reported above only finds the external weakly convex polyhedron in which my irregular icosahedron is inscribed. As I said, I guess I will have to work on this much more.